# Mobius Function and Triangular Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, mobius-function

The Mobius function for the positive integers µ : $\mathbb Z^+$ → {$−1,0,1$} is deﬁned on page 17 of the course notes. The triangular numbers are the positive integers of the form  $n \choose 2$ for $n ≥ 2.$  The triangular numbers $n \choose 2$ and $n+1 \choose 2$ are said to be consecutive triangular numbers. Prove that the longest sequence of consecutive triangular numbers each having nonzero Mobius function value is of length six.

I understand the Mobius function and triangular numbers, but I'm not sure how to prove this problem. I know that the first 6 triangular numbers have nonzero Mobius values, but I am not sure how to formally demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Can you show that if $n=8m$ or $8m+1$ then $n \choose 2$ is divisible by $4$?

Comment: so the 7th triangular number is 28, which is divisible by 4, the µ(28) = 0. Therefore,  (8m-1) and (8k) triangular numbers are both divisible by 4 and hence their Möbius function value is zero. Thus for any natural number k, only (8m+1), (8m+2) , (8m+3) , (8m+4), (8m+5), (8m+6) triangular numbers can possibly have nonzero Möbius value.


Is this correct?

Comment: @lz97:  I think you have the idea, though you sometimes wrote $k$ when you meant $m$